# Type mismatch when comparing an NSUInteger to 0

Tags: objective-c

I am writing a unit test for an object that has an NSUInteger property and I'm getting a type mismatch when I compare to 0.  Can someone explain why?

My object definition:

```
@interface Item : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger n;

// stuff deleted...
@end
```

And the line from my unit test that gets a type mismatch error:

```
STAssertEquals(0, i.n, @"n property should be zero");
```

I also tried 0L and I get a type mismatch with that as well.  I have worked around this by declaring an NSUInteger variable called "zero" and setting that to 0, then using that for the compare, but I'd like to better understand what's going on here.

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you included the full text of the type mismatch error.

Comment: It seems that you are unsing iOS? Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that the macro `STAssertEquals` uses `strcmp(@encode(__typeof__(a1)), @encode(__typeof__(a2))` to decide if the two parameters have the same type. If not, the macro raises an exception with the message "Type mismatch -- "...

So you cannot use `STAssertEquals` on compatible types, they have to match exactly:

```
STAssertEquals((NSUInteger)0, i.n, @"n property should be zero");
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes the literal 0 as an int instead of an NSUInteger.

Use instead (NSUinteger)0

```
STAssertEquals((NSUInteger)0, i.n, @"n property should be zero");
```

To avoid discussions whether NSUInteger is unsigned log or unsigned int...this is from Apple NSObjCRuntime.h:

```
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

So in iOS is unsigned int and in other platforms could vary.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `0uL`? [NSUInteger is `unsigned long`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW71).

Comment: On iOS `NSUInteger` is `unsigned int`.

Comment: Apple defines NSUInteger inside a conditional depending on the platform, so both of you are right, it depends on the platform.

Comment: @KennyTM Right. The discussion in your link suggests that the documentation is just copied over from Mac OS (there is no 64 bit iOS, yet). File a bug.

Comment: See my answer for NSUinteger