# STAssertEquals: null pointer and NULL gives type mismatch error

Tags: ios, unit-testing, sentestingkit

What is wrong, here I am doing?

`ptr == NULL` is `true`,

This is also ok,

`STAssertTrue(ptr == NULL, @"ptr is null");` //succeeded

But,

```
STAssertEquals(ptr, NULL, @"");
```

is giving error, "`Type mismatch ---` ".

```
- (void) testNilEncoding {
    NSString * nils = nil;
    const char * ptr = [nils dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding].bytes;
    const char * ptr2 = [nils cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if (ptr == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Ptr is null"); // ok
    }
    STAssertTrue(ptr == NULL, @"ptr is null"); //ok
    STAssertEquals(ptr, NULL, @""); //fails
    STAssertEquals(ptr2, NULL, @""); //fails
}
```

Comment: This is a side effect of how the assertion macros are implemented. You would have to do a cast like `STAssertEquals((void*)ptr, NULL, nil);`

Comment: Similar Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578536/type-mismatch-when-comparing-an-nsuinteger-to-0.